# How to complete the square of this polynomia

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, completing-the-square

let:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2+4x+5}$$

I am trying to complete the square in order to use trig substitution but I failed I was trying:

$$(x^2+4x+1)+5-1$$
$$(x^2+4x+1)+4$$

Comment: Tabe the half of $b=4$ and square it and get 4. Add and subtract $4$ : $x^2+4x+4-4+5=(x+2)^2-4+5=(x+2)^2+1$

Comment: @callculus42 thanks

Comment: You're welcome   It pleases me that aeverything is clar now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{x^2+4x+5}$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int \frac{dx}{(x+2)^2+1}$$
Let substitute $(x+2)=t$
then we can see

$$I=\int \frac{dt}{t^2+1}$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\arctan(t)+c$$
So $I=\arctan(x+2)+c$ where $c$ is an arbitary integral constant